Siunitx error with digitsep range-phrase
I'm getting the following error with my up-to-date install of siunitx:

! LaTeX Error: The key 'siunitx/digitsep' is unknown and is being ignored.
For immediate help type H .
...
l.165 ...e, digitsep={, }, range-phrase = \text{--}}

This is triggered from a sequence of calls

(PathTo/MiKTeX/tex/latex/pdfpages/ppluatex.def))

(PathTo/MiKTeX/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty
(PathTo/MiKTeX/tex/latex/translations/translations.sty
(PathTo/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty)))
which worked fine the last time I ran this.


My install uses siunitx.sty which doesn't include digitsep, whereas CTAN has siunitx-v2.sty which does.
It's easy enough to patch this, but what's the "official" way of handling the issue?

Please show the entire command that generates the error message.

Well spotted!!! I'm missing a file  "BSM_1.hst" not found. Thanks.

It's not the actual problem but it;s years since I've run this version of the program and I'd forgotten about a legacy bit of it.

@DLyons So is the question a 'local issue'?

Thanks for the reply Joseph. I'm not sure what's going on.  About two years ago I had a working progam using siunitx (which is an excellent package!).  I came back to it today on a new  Windows machine and did a MikTeX package update so I have a current version  of siunitx.sty (which doen't reference digitsep).  I then go into a package that implements custom key/value tables using  xparse. None of its internals have chaged but now for the first time it refers to digitsep. I can just switch to  siunitx-v2 but I wasn't sure why it existed (as opposed to an update of  siunitx itself),
